# MySQL Workbench Saving Database

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a group project and my partner sent me a .mwb file so I could take a look at what they did for the ER diagram, but she can't figure out how to send a .sql file for the database itself (at least I think those are .sql files). How do you save and send a database to someone? I am trying to test the database by writing some queries, but I don't know how to do that if all I can look at is the Diagram. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `Heidi SQL` managers bulk maintenance.

Comment: Our class is supposed to use MySQL Workbench, is there any way to do it with that program?

Comment: I think MySQL workbench provides administrator tools to do that too.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL work bench can definitely do this for you.

here is one link where you have some screenshots too : [Back up and restore MySQL databases using MySQL Workbench](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/1404/~/back-up-and-restore-mysql-databases-using-mysql-workbench)

It shows how to do both export and import of a database backup.